# Riesz Representation Theorem: isomorph

Tags: hilbert-spaces, duality-theorems, riesz-representation-theorem

Riesz' Representation Theorem states that every linear functional can be represented by a vector. This shows that the Dual can be ANTILINEARLY and norm preserving identified with the Hilbert Space itself.

---

I'm now wondering:
Is it also possible (maybe in a completely different fashion) to LINEARLY and norm preserving identify the Dual (not the "Antidual") with the Hilbert Space?
In any, case is there a proof for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Fix a *total orthogonal system* $(e_i)_i$ on your Hilbert space $H$ and consider the conjugation of coordinations:
$$\varphi:\sum_i\alpha_ie_i \ \mapsto \ \sum_i\bar{\alpha_i}e_i$$
this is an antilinear isomorphism of $H$ to itself, so composing it with the Riesz presentation $H^*\to H$ gives a linear isomorphism $H^*\to H$.