# Dual Spaces and Topological Vector Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, self-learning, topological-vector-spaces

I have a question regarding ***dual spaces***.

Before, let me write that this all issue looks really problematic to me, and I already touched it quickly in another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109143/weak-topologies-and-weak-convergence-looking-for-feedbacks). However, in that occasion, the focus was slightly different and I was advised to ask a separate question. Thus, here there is my new question.

**Question:**

1. *Given a topological vector space $X$, how do we* know (decide?) *what is its dual?*
2. *Do we get this information through the Riesz Representation Theorems?*
3. *If we have a couple of dual spaces, are they interchangeable (i.e. one is the dual of the other)?*

As always, any feedback or explanation will be greatly welcome.

Thank you for your time.

*PS: I do hope the question does not look too naive, but being self-thaught (I know I tend to repeat this too often, but I think it is relevant) I think I have exactly the kind of questions concerning the general intuition and relation between different objects that are usually addressed in a class by professors or tutors in the flesh.*

Comment: There is not *the* dual. As a vector space, the dual is the set of bounded linear functionals, but this can be endowed with several different topologies making it into a topological vector space. In some case there's a natural choice (for Banach spaces the operator norm is usually chosen), but not in general.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks a lot for the comment. So, (cause it is there that I want to get the intuition), starting with a Polish space $X$, how does it happen that $\Delta (X)$ is its dual, where $\Delta (X)$ denotes the set of all probability measures on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B} (X)$?

Comment: @egreg Bounded means "continuous for the topology", by analogy with the normed case ?

Comment: @RobertGreen Yes, so. Always confusing.

Comment: @egreg: I am asking that, hoping it is true for my intuition, because for what I have got so far, **if it is true**, then we should be able to endow $\Delta (X)$ with the ***weak-star topology***, which should be nothing more than ***the topology of weak convergence***, right?

Comment: @Kolmin A long time has passed since I studied functional analysis. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: Thanks anyway for your feedback. :-)

Comment: @egreg: Sorry if I'm mistaken, but there *is* the dual of a tvs, namely the space of all its continuous linear functionals. What you refer to is rather the question what topology *can* be put instead of its original topology.

Comment: @Freeze_S The fact is that the space of continuous linear functionals doesn't have a topology, until we decide which one we endow it with. There are many possible topologies on function spaces. The problem of reflexivity depends of course on what topology we choose. So there is *the* “abstract” dual, but not *the* topology on it.

Comment: @egreg: Yes so as I said there *is* the dual space but as you rightly mentioned it doesn't come equipped with topology yet.

Comment: @Kolmin: In case you consider the probability measures on a Polish space you'll get a cone only. Instead you can regard the continuous functions over a locally compact Hausdorff space vanishing at infinity. That is Banach space. Here its dual is identifyable with the regular complex Borel measures: $\mathcal{C}_\infty(\Omega)'\cong\mathcal{M}(\Omega):l(f):=\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}\mu$ Note this algebraic identification becomes even an isometry when one chooses the uniform norm topology on its dual: $\|l\|:=\sup_{f\in\mathcal{C}_\infty(\Omega):\|f\|_\infty\leq1}|l(f)|$

Comment: @Freeze_S: You wrote "In case you consider the probability measures on a Polish space you'll get a **cone** only". Honestly, I cannot *see* this statement at all, most probably because I don't know the meaning of cone in this context.

Comment: @Kolmin: Ah no worry. A cone is a vector space except that you can multiply only by positiv scalars. So if you take positive measures you'll get a cone that is you can multiply a positive measure by a positive number *only* to obtain another positive measure. It becomes even worse if you restrict yourself to probability measures. ...

Comment: ... The right object to study Polish spaces in context of functional analysis are the regular complex measures. Those ones you can multiply by any complex number to obtain another regular complex measure. Even more they become a Banach space by w.r.t. to their total variation norm. *(I was thinking of joining this into my answer below, however, I think this fits better into a thread specifically on this problem. If you're still interested I'll open a thread on this.)*

Comment: @Kolmin: Besides I had the same problems. So don't worry, you're questions *are* very good!

Answer (score 2):

**Algebraic Dual**

Given a vector space.

Consider its algebraic dual:
$$V^*:=\mathcal{L}(V,\mathbb{C})$$
*(Remark: This won't be of to much interest!)*

**Topological Dual**

Given a topological vector space.

Consider its topological dual:
$$V':=\mathcal{L}(V,\mathbb{C})\cap\mathcal{C}(V,\mathbb{C})$$
*(It obtains algebraic structure by pointwise operations.)*

Regard the dual pairing:
$$V'\times V:\quad(f,v):=f(v)$$

Introduce its evaluations:
$$\varepsilon_v(f):=(f,v)=f(v)$$

It can be endowed with the dual topology:
$$\mathcal{T}(V'):=\tau\left(\bigcup_{v\in V}\varepsilon_v^{-1}\mathcal{T}(\mathbb{C})\right)$$
*(Warning: This won't be the only topology on the dual!)*

**Bounded Dual**

Given a Banach space.

Consider its bounded dual:
$$E':=\mathcal{L}(E,\mathbb{C})\cap\mathcal{B}(E,\mathbb{C})$$
*(It is identical to the topological dual!)*

It is a Banach space itself with:
$$\|f\|:=\sup_{x\in E:\|x\|\leq1}|f(x)|$$
*(Note: This gives another topology on the dual!)*

**Hilbert Dual**

Given a Hilbert space.

Riesz identifies the dual space by:
$$\delta_\eta\varphi:=\langle\eta,\varphi\rangle:\quad\Phi:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}':\eta\mapsto\delta_\eta$$
*(Caution: The scalar product is another dual pairing!)*

This identification is antilinear:
$$\varepsilon_{\varphi+\psi}=\varepsilon_\varphi+\varepsilon_\psi\quad\varepsilon_{\lambda\varphi}=\overline{\lambda}\varepsilon_\varphi$$

Especially, it is an isometry:
$$\|\varepsilon_\varphi\|=\|\varphi\|$$
*(Hint: It allows a noncanonical linear isometry!*)*

**Measure Dual**

*In a new thread: Riesz-Markov-Kakutani*

**Reference**

*See the thread: [Riesz: Isomorphy](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/602003/79762)

Comment: Thanks a lot! As always, lot of things to metabolise. However, in all honesty, what I think I lack are not definitions, but rather general intuition, the same intuition that you gave me splendidly in your extended comments to my old question on weak topologies, in which you rather straightforwardly answered to my original questions. Anyway, I am seriously thinking to put a bounty on this question.

Comment: Nooo don't do that; save your bounties for grey days. ;)

Comment: Besides, you got me on a new idea: The scalar product itself is another dual pairing. So the question arises: Does the dual topology here coincide with the usual topology induced by its norm: $\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{H}):=\bigcap_{\eta\in\mathcal{H}}\langle\eta,\mathcal{T}( \mathbb{C} )\rangle\quad\mathcal{B}_0(\mathcal{H}):=\|\mathcal{B}_0(\mathbb{R}_+)\|^{-1}$